# "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" durng using port tunelling

Tags: keycloak

I have keycloak installed on k8s cluster. It is accessible on some port, let say 8000. The problem is that i do not have that port open on firewall(it is quite hard to do) so i connected via ssh to node and create a tunel to my localhost. Now the problem is that i'm getting error "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri". Is there any way to disable that without access to keycloak via web? I have access to keycloak pod. The version is 18.0.0 still on wilfdly.